# Android - automatically finding and making a setOnClickListener for every button

Tags: java, android

I have dozens of buttons, each of which I want to do the following for:

```
Button abcdefg = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.abcdefg);
        abcdefg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                audiotoplay = "abcdefg";
                playAudio(audiotoplay);
            }
        });
```

In this case is there a simpler way to do this for every button than copying and pasting this code block for every button and just replacing `abcdefg` with each buttons ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In strings.xml create a string array containing as strings the ids of the buttons, like:

```
<string-array name="buttonids">
    <item>abc</item>
    <item>def</item>
    <item>ghi</item>
</string-array>
```

and then in your activity, get this array and for each string id get the integer id of the button with `getIdentifier()`. 
Then by `findViewById()` get a reference to each button and set the listener:

```
String[] buttonids = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.buttonids);
for (String buttonid : buttonids) {
    final String name = buttonid;
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());
    Button button = findViewById(id);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            audiotoplay = name;
            playAudio(audiotoplay);
        }
    });
}
```

I assume that as in your sample code, you will assign the string id of each button to the variable `audiotoplay`.
If you add or remove buttons in your app, the only change you have to do is add or remove its string id from the array in `strings.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try butterknife, https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

```
@OnClick(R.id.submit1)
@OnClick(R.id.submit2) 
@OnClick(R.id.submit3) 
@OnClick(R.id.submit4)  
void submit() {
    // Clicked ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a class that extends from Button and define that specific behaviour there. After that you need to update your layout .xml to use your new class instead of the default one.

I'm not sure about the use case - but if you need the id you can save that as the button tag and then access it from *OnClick*.

For example:

```
public class YourButtonClass extends AppCompatButton {

....

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            audiotoplay = getTag();
            playAudio(audiotoplay);
        }
    });
}
```

}

in your activity/ fragment:

```
findViewById<YourButtonClass>(R.id.btn_your_button).setTag("123")
```

and on your layout:

```
<this.is.your.package.name.YourButtonClass
    android:id="@+id/btn_your_button"
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use tags. Each button in the layout xml should have

```
android:onClick="buttonClick"
android:tag="abcd1234"
```

Then you should have a single function in your **Activity**

```
public void buttonClick(View v) { 
    audiotoplay = v.getTag();
    playAudio(audiotoplay); 
}
```

You do not have to call any setOnClickListener, as it is set in the xml. Just make sure the `buttonClick` method is in your **Activity** class, not *Fragment* class. You can call it any name you like, I just used buttonClick to differentiate from any other onClick. If you must have it in Fragment, then you would assign a single onClickListener to a variable (or have the Fragment implement onClickListener) with same code, and call setOnClickListener on all buttons to it.